# Way the productColors: this.builder.control([]) doesn't bind correctly in angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

When I add its work fine it is add form controls correctly and add the array of object for product Sizes control correctly also add array of color inside product Sizes correctly but in edit mode the product Sizes was displayed but the array of color inside product Sizes doesn't displayed
note : when i print the form after set value thr colors was inside it but it is doesnot bind correctly.

my Form is :

```
productForm = this.builder.group({
    id: this.builder.control(-1),   
    name:  this.builder.control(''),   
    description: this.builder.control(''),
    salePrice: this.builder.control(null),
    isActive: this.builder.control(true),   
    productSizes: this.builder.array([]),
  });
```

I have this code in type script file

```
formSize : any; //form array

  get sizesArray(){
    return this.productForm.get('productSizes') as FormArray;
  } 

  get productColorsArray() {
    return this.builder.control([]);
  }

  generateRowForSizeAndColors() {
  return this.builder.group({
    sizeId: this.builder.control(-1),
    sizeNameAr: this.builder.control(''),
    sizeName: this.builder.control(''),
    oldPrice: this.builder.control(null),
    salePrice: this.builder.control(null),

    productColors: this.builder.control([])
   });
  }

  addSizes() {
    this.formSize = this.productForm.get('productSizes') as FormArray;
    this.formSize.push(this.generateRowForSizeAndColors());
  }

  removeSizes(index: number){
    this.formSize = this.productForm.get('productSizes') as FormArray;
    this.formSize.removeAt(index);
  }
```

My HTML file :

```
<table class="table-bordered table-responsive" style="width: 100%; border-color:#ccc" formArrayName="productSizes">
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="text-center">
                      <td class="col-5 p-2">
                        <mat-label>Size</mat-label>
                      </td>
                      <td class="col-5 p-2">
                        <mat-label>Colors</mat-label>
                      </td>                                         
                      <td class="col-1 p-2">
                        <div class="btn-primary rounded p-1" style="cursor: pointer;"(click)="addSizes()">
                          <span class="size-18 p-1">Add Row</span>
                        </div>            
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of sizesArray?.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                      <td class="p-2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 100%;">
                          <mat-label>select size</mat-label>
                          <mat-select name="size" formControlName="sizeId">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let sizs of sizes" [value]="sizs.id">
                              {{sizs.nameAr}}
                            </mat-option>
                          </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </td>
                    
                      <td class="p-2">
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width: 100%;">
                          <mat-label>select colors</mat-label>
                          <mat-select name="color" formControlName="productColors" multiple>

                            <mat-select-trigger>
                              <mat-label class="padding-sides" *ngFor="let item of item.get('productColors')?.value" >
                                <i class="bi bi-square-fill size-18" [style.color]="item?.nameAr"></i>
                              </mat-label>
                            </mat-select-trigger>

                            <mat-option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color">
                              <i class="bi bi-square-fill size-24" [style.color]="color?.nameAr"></i>
                            </mat-option>
                            
                          </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                      </td>
                                                                       
                      <td class="p-2 text-center">
                          <i class="bi bi-trash size-22 cursor" style="color: red;" (click)="removeSizes(i)"></i>                   
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>         
                </table>
```

the shape of value for my response to set it to form is :

```
`id :112
name : "T-Shirt"
description :"test"
salePrice : 50
isActive : true
productSizes: Array(2)
0: 
oldPrice: 0
productColors: Array(2)
 0: 
 {id: 22, name: '#07c3f2', isActive: true}
 1: 
 {id: 21, name: '#db1414', isActive: true}
 length: 2
 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

salePrice: 0
sizeId: 5
sizeName: "Free Size"

[[Prototype]]: Object`
```

the array of color inside productSizes control displayed correctly

like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjd3V.png

Insted of :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbfYF.png